# Compile error while building Blender from source on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: compile

I am following [this](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu) guide for compiling blender from source on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am getting the following compile

```
[ 11%] Building CXX object intern/cycles/blender/CMakeFiles/bf_intern_cycles.dir/blender_camera.cpp.o
In file included from /home/vvy/Documents/Compiled/blender-git/blender/intern/cycles/graph/node_enum.h:20:0,
                 from /home/vvy/Documents/Compiled/blender-git/blender/intern/cycles/graph/node_type.h:19,
                 from /home/vvy/Documents/Compiled/blender-git/blender/intern/cycles/graph/node.h:19,
                 from /home/vvy/Documents/Compiled/blender-git/blender/intern/cycles/render/camera.h:22,
                 from /home/vvy/Documents/Compiled/blender-git/blender/intern/cycles/blender/blender_camera.cpp:17:
/home/vvy/Documents/Compiled/blender-git/blender/intern/cycles/util/util_param.h:31:69: error: the type ‘const OpenImageIO::v1_6::TypeDesc’ of constexpr variable ‘ccl::TypeFloat2’ is not literal
 static constexpr TypeDesc TypeFloat2(TypeDesc::FLOAT, TypeDesc::VEC2);
```

I'm on the `master` branch of the `blender` project.

Any help in resolving this error are appreciated. 
Thanks.